# Danish letters MySQL output

Tags: php, mysql, database, collation

I got some `varchar` fields in my MySQL database containing danish letters (æ, ø, å). When browsing the database with *phpmyadmin*, the letters appear correctly, however when I obtain the field through a query, and try to display the field, they are changed ("ø" becomes "Ã¸"). I tried changing the collation to both latin1 and utf-8 (both danish versions), but without luck. I can't even figure out if it is the database or my code that is the issue. Anyone who has seen this before?

Edit: I'm adding the code to read and display the database content. The issue is confirmed in the "users_last_name" and "address_street", but is likely present all over (currently these are the only fields with danish letters).

Code:

```
<?php
// Query to load information on projects
$main_query = $this->db->query('SELECT project_id, project_name, project_image_src, project_owner FROM ed_projects');
foreach ($main_query->result() as $row) {
    // Get adress of the current project in the "foreach" loop
    $project_id    = $row->project_id;
    $address_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ed_project_address WHERE project_id='$project_id'");
    $address_row   = $address_query->row();

    // Get the name of the user who owns the current project
    $user_id       = $row->project_owner;
    $user_query    = $this->db->query("SELECT users_first_name, users_last_name FROM ed_users WHERE id='$user_id'");
    $user_row      = $user_query->row();
?>

<div class="projectAvatar">
    <?php if ($row->project_image_src) {
        echo "<img src=".$row->project_image_src.">";
    } else {
        echo "NoImg";
    }
    ?>
</div>

<div class="projectInformation">
    <?php echo $row->project_name; ?>  <br />
    <?php echo $address_row->address_street." ".$address_row->address_number; ?> <br />
    <?php echo $user_row->users_first_name." ".$user_row->users_last_name; ?> <br />
</div>

<?php 
}
```

Comment: By the way, I am using the CodeIgniter framework, if that is relevant...

Comment: You may want to read [Joel on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html); long but worthwhile if you're going to be dealing with Unicode/character encoding regularly. In the meantime, can you tell us exactly how you "obtain the field through a query", from start to finish, e.g. is this coming out on a web page, being driven through PHP, etc., etc. (Your problem is likely to be the character encoding set somewhere along the route, most likely in your HTML, if you're outputting to a web page.)

Comment: (Incidentally, the collation probably won't make any difference—collations determine sort order; character sets determine the actual character encoding. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-general.html)

Comment: I added the code I am using to the original post. Also I am reading like crazy :-). It seems to be a nice article.

Comment: Thanks for the code in the update. However, what we need to see is the character encoding of your web page as a whole (these days, with HTML5, this is usually set with a meta header element like `<meta charset="utf-8">`.) If the character set is incorrect, or missing, you'll see this kind of problem.

Comment: I had similiar issues before, and solved it by setting utf-8 on the client.
[link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Comment: I know this is likely the wrong answer, but I dont have anything on charset in the header... (I feel "oops" is likely a good word now)

Comment: Hey, that's okay, this stuff is complicated and everyone gets to learn it at some point ;) If you're using an HTML5 doctype, try just adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `<head>` section of the page and see if things magically start working.

Comment: Ah yes, very much "oops". I added the line you suggested, and now it works. Could you possibly write that suggestion as an answer (rather than a comment), so I can accept it. That way it can help other code-newbies in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If things are working in phpMyAdmin, but not on your own web pages, it's likely to be a problem with the character encoding of your web pages. Assuming you're using an HTML5 doctype, try just adding:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

to the `<HEAD>` section of your site.

Basically, from your comments and code, it seems like you're successfully storing your Danish characters using UTF-8 encoding in your database. (The table's collation setting won't affect that; collations determine sort orders and comparisons, but not the actual character set used for storage.) To make characters appear correctly on a web page, you need to tell the browser what character encoding you're using for your page; adding the `<meta charset...>` header does this. phpMyAdmin's web pages will almost certainly be using UTF-8 as their character set, so if that's working, you should change your pages to match it.

As I mentioned, I feel that by far the best full explanation of how this all works is given in Joel Spolsky's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), which will tell you about how this stuff should be done in all its gory detail.

Comment: As danish characters is "æ, ø, å, Æ, Ø, Å", you are absolutely correct. UTF-8 should do the fix.

Comment: As stated in the above discussion, this does indeed work. Thank you very much for the fast answer.

Answer (score -2):

try this ANSI (Windows-1252).
read from

[Differences Between Character Sets](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp)